# Camel aggregator does not aggregate all

Tags: apache-camel, aggregator

I am splitting some java objects and then aggregating. I am kind of confused how this completion strategy works with Camel (2.15.2). I am using completion size and completion timeout. If I understand correctly, completion timeout does not have much effect in it. Because, there is not much waiting going on here.

Altogether, I have 3000+ objects. But, it seems only a part of it is aggregated. But, if I vary the completion size value, situation changes. If the size is 100, it aggregates around 800, and if it is 200, it aggregates up to around 1600. But, I don't know the size of objects in advance, and so, cannot rely on a assumed number.

Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here?
If I use eagerCheckCompletion, it aggregates the whole thing in a one go, which I don't want.
Below is my route:

```
   from("direct:specializeddatavalidator")
        .to("bean:headerFooterValidator").split(body())
        .process(rFSStatusUpdater)
        .process(dataValidator).choice()
        .when(header("discrepencyList").isNotNull()).to("seda:errorlogger")
        .otherwise().to("seda:liveupdater").end();


    from("seda:liveupdater?concurrentConsumers=4&timeout=5000")
        .aggregate(simple("${in.header.contentType}"),
                batchAggregationStrategy())
        .completionSize(MAX_RECORDS)
        .completionTimeout(BATCH_TIME_OUT).to("bean:liveDataUpdater");

    from("seda:errorlogger?concurrentConsumers=4")
        .aggregate(simple("${in.header.contentType}"),
                batchAggregationStrategy("discrepencyList"))
        .completionSize(MAX_RECORDS_FOR_ERRORS)
        .completionTimeout(BATCH_TIME_OUT)
        .process(errorProcessor).to("bean:liveDataUpdater");
```

Answer (score 2):

Weird, but if you want to aggregate all the splitted messages you can simply use

```
.split(body(), batchAggregationStrategy())
```

And depending on how you want it to work you can use

```
.shareUnitOfWork().stopOnException()
```

See http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html for more info

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I wanted to know, whats wrong with mine! It seems if I change the seda endpoints into direct, it starts working as I expect! Don't know why!

Comment: Making a simple testcase and post it would help a lot :)

Comment: Sorry for late response. I wish I had the time to do a simple test case to prove my point. Anyway, it seems, there was something to do how the application was running. It was inside a simple main class with a sleep method for a fixed time. And, also, it did not have right completion logic which I added later. I would share some code, if anyone thinks that would be useful for them.

Comment: @Mashrur, Can you share the code? I have problem in aggregating and maybe your example could help. [Here is the question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768431/apachel-camel-zip-doesnt-create-one-zip)